# MobileCapableWebFormViewEngine Blackberry

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to detect the mobile device use MobileCapableWebFormViewEngine it works well for all devices except for Blackberry because the User Agent contains for example BlackBerry9550 or other Blackberry identifications (BlackBerryxxx).  I am using the following code:
if (request.UserAgent.Contains("BlackBerry"))
            {
                result = base.FindView(controllerContext, "Mobile/BlackBerry/" + viewName, masterName, useCache);
            } 
I also tried:
if (request.UserAgent.Contains("BlackBerry")
{
 result = base.FindView(controllerContext, "Mobile/BlackBerry/" + viewName, masterName, useCache);
}

Any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string userAgent = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;
if (userAgent.IndexOf("BlackBerry", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)    
{
  result = base.FindView(controllerContext, "Mobile/BlackBerry/" + viewName, masterName, useCache);
}
```